# KnockoutJS bindingHandler calling init, when modal is re-shown

Tags: knockout.js

Im using knockout js in conjunction with Bootstrap to display a modal window on a page. I also have the following extension to grab values from the markup so that my observables can be populdated from razor:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.initializeValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        valueAccessor()(element.getAttribute('value'));

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if (element.nodeName == 'SPAN')
            element.innerHTML = value;

        element.setAttribute('value', value);

    }
};
```

This works great an populates the knockout view model the first time the page is loaded with values from razor. When I update the value from inside the modal the update is called, and the observable is updated and all that. The problem is when I close the modal window, and reopen it. It calls the init again on the bindingHandler and resets the value from the origonal value attribute despite the fact that I am setting the attribute to the new value at the bottom of the update function.

So my question for you all is: Why is the initialize being called again when the modal is reopened? I know the markup is bring removed from the DOM when the modal is hidden, but shouldnt the values on the modals observable still be in memory?

The following is my view model for the whole page, and the view model for the popup:

```
var userEditViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.template = 'editUserTemplate';
            self.hasChanges = ko.observable(false);
            self.isCanceling = ko.observable(false);

            self.FirstName = ko.observable();
            self.LastName = ko.observable();
            self.EmailAddress = ko.observable();

            self.onYes = function() {
                self.modal.close();
                self.isCanceling(false);
                self.hasChanges(false);
            };

            self.onNo = function () {
                self.isCanceling(false);
            };

            self.onSave = function () {
                if (self.errors().length == 0) {
                    var options =
                    {
                        FirstName: self.FirstName(),
                        LastName: self.LastName(),
                        Email: self.EmailAddress()
                    };
                    repo.SaveProfile(options, function (result) {
                        self.modal.close(result.result);
                    });
                } else {
                    self.errors.showAllMessages();
                }
            };

            self.onCancel = function () {
                if (self.hasChanges() == false) {
                    this.modal.close();
                } else {
                    self.isCanceling(true);
                }
            };

            self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
        }

        }

        var profileViewModel = (function () {
            var self = this;

            self.FirstName = ko.observable();
            self.LastName = ko.observable();
            self.EmailAddress = ko.observable();

            self.EditUserModel = new userEditViewModel();

            self.EditUser = function () {
                bhn.ShowModal({
                    viewModel: self.EditUserModel,
                    context: this 
                })
                .done(function (result) {

                })
                .fail(function () {

                })
                .then(self._updateProfile);
            }

            self._updateProfile = (function (result) {
                self.FirstName(result.firstName);
                self.LastName(result.lastName);
                self.EmailAddress(result.email);

            });
        });
```

And the modal code:

```
function createModal(templateName, viewModel) {
    var temporaryDiv = addHiddenDivToBody();
    var deferredElement = $.Deferred();

    ko.renderTemplate(
        templateName,
        viewModel,
        {
            afterRender: function (nodes) {
                var elements = nodes.filter(function (node) {
                    return node.nodeType === 1;
                });
                deferredElement.resolve(elements[0]);
            }
        },
        temporaryDiv,
        "replaceNode"
    );

    return deferredElement;
}

function showModal(options) {
    if (typeof options === "undefined" || options === null) throw new Error("An options argument is required.");
    if (typeof options.viewModel !== "object") throw new Error("options.viewModel is required.");

    var viewModel = options.viewModel;
    var template = options.template || viewModel.template;
    var context = options.context;

    if (!template) throw new Error("options.template or options.viewModel.template is required.");

    return createModal(template, viewModel)
        .pipe($)
        .pipe(function ($ui) {
            var deferredModalResult = $.Deferred();
            addModalHelperToViewModel(viewModel, deferredModalResult, context);
            showTwitterBootstrapModal($ui);
            whenModalResultCompleteThenHideUi(deferredModalResult, $ui);
            whenUiHiddenThenRemoveUi($ui);
            return deferredModalResult;
        });

}

function addHiddenDivToBody() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    return div;
};

function addModalHelperToViewModel(viewModel, deferredModalResult, context) {
    viewModel.modal = {
        close: function (result) {
            if (typeof result !== "undefined") {
                deferredModalResult.resolveWith(context, [result]);
            } else {
                deferredModalResult.rejectWith(context, []);
            }
        }
    };
};

function showTwitterBootstrapModal($ui) {
    // Display the modal UI using Twitter Bootstrap's modal plug-in.
    $ui.modal({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
    });
};

function whenModalResultCompleteThenHideUi(deferredModalResult, $ui) {
    deferredModalResult.always(function () {
        $ui.modal("hide");
    });
};

function whenUiHiddenThenRemoveUi($ui) {
    $ui.on("hidden", function () {
        //$ui.each(function (index, element) { ko.cleanNode(element); });
        //$ui.remove();
    });
};
```

Comment: what lib provides the `bhn.ShowModal`? I guess that lib calls `ko.cleanNode` on modal close, and calls `ko.applyBinding(..., node);` to init the binding every time when you call `bhn.ShowModal(...)`.

Comment: Indeed you are correct it was calling cleannode, however I commented that bit out and now its just calling modal('hide') and still calling init when I reopen the modal.

Comment: guess you have to find the line calling `applyBindings` and make it conditional.